# WPF c# - Using a DataGrid for end user data entry and setting focus to first cell when app opens

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have started converting an app from FlashBuilder/Flex to a Windows Form app and I had a DataGridView that received focus on the first cell of the first row/column ready for the end user to enter data with a keyboard or scan a barcode, and it worked well in testing. But I wanted to style the buttons, combobox, datagridview, etc. and I was told that switching to a WPF Application would give me this flexibility. So I have and so far have the buttons, combobox and checkbox styled and working as I want them, but I have found a big difference (and very steep learning curve) with WPF especially with the DataGrid.

1. The DataGrid ideally will show alternating colored rows (already have that set) already showing there when the app opens - at the moment there is a single row ready for input, but I would like the table filled with empty rows (preferably only the first row editable until it is populated and moved to the next row).
2. When the app opens I would like that first cell at column 0 and row 0 to be selected and ready to edit with the text prompt showing.
3. The Datagrid has two columns and I do not want the second column to receive focus when tab is used, and it is not to allow data entry (I have it set to IsReadOnly=true, but it still receives focus).
4. Once the data is entered into the row and the input is on a new row, previous rows are not allowed to be changed/selected, they need to be locked.

I have been searching the web for days and trying all kinds of methods and none appear to work, I hope this is just a rookie mistake otherwise I will need to return to a Windows Form App and maybe third party controls to achieve my styling requirements.

So far in my MainWindow() I have the following...

```
ObservableCollection<DataItem> items = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
scannedItems.ItemsSource = items;
```

And this...

```
    public class DataItem
    {
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string Instruments { get; set; }
    }
```

This will add the initial row which I can manually select and enter the data, but I would like that first row/column already selected ready for data entry by the end user.

if I add this line (or anything else that selects that first row) the application starts in a break state...

```
scannedItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

This is if I have the SelectionUnit set to Cell, if it is set to Row, the first row is highlighted, but I must still click on the first column to start entering data.

Maybe I am creating the DataGrid incorrectly for input, as I want it unbound from anything and when the user clicks save, it will then extract the entered data and save it to a database.

I have also tried this in the Window_Loaded event...

```
scannedItems.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(scannedItems);
SelectRowByIndex(scannedItems, 0);


    public static void SelectRowByIndex(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex)
    {
        if (!dataGrid.SelectionUnit.Equals(DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow))
            throw new ArgumentException("The SelectionUnit of the DataGrid must be set to FullRow.");

        if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > (dataGrid.Items.Count - 1))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is an invalid row index.", rowIndex));

        dataGrid.SelectedItems.Clear();
        // set the SelectedItem property 
        object item = dataGrid.Items[rowIndex]; // = Product X
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = item;

        DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        if (row == null)
        {
            // bring the data item (Product object) into view
            // in case it has been virtualized away
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
            row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        }
        //TODO: Retrieve and focus a DataGridCell object
    }
```

this is my DataGrid in the XAML...

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="scannedItems" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Height="294" 
        Margin="325,52,12,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="463" 
        HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFCCCCCC" 
        VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFCCCCCC" 
        ClipboardCopyMode="None" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        FontFamily="Arial" 
        HeadersVisibility="Column" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DGCHeaderStyle}" 
        BorderBrush="#FF656F69" 
        CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
        CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="0" FontSize="12"
        SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFEFFAF3" RowBackground="White" RowHeight="19" EnableRowVirtualization="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Barcode,Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Barcode" Width="176" IsReadOnly="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Instruments,Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Cycle Item(s)" Width="268" IsReadOnly="True" Selector.IsSelected="False">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Hopefully I have added enough background info to give you an idea. Hopefully I am not asking too much for the application, but essentially I already have this running as described in Flash Builder and my current test Windows Form application.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.